# Node-red error while installing arduino node

Tags: node.js, arduino, node-red

> [arduino] Error: Cannot find module 'firmata/node_modules/serialport

This is the error shown while installing arduino node in node-red

After installing arduino nodes and restarting node-red following is displayed on the console:
[image]

I also can not see the nodes installed on server.

Comment: No where near enough information here for anybody to help

Comment: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build: what does this statement means

Comment: it says "warn", not "error", so the title's off. what does "arduino node" mean?

Comment: it is a node which creates interface with arduino uno and is installed using command npm install node-red-node-arduino.

Comment: Hi - to help we'd need to see what was logged when you installed the arduino node. The log you've shared is when you run node-red, so doesn't say anything about what happened at install time.